# Problems with Responsiveness on Mobile WordPress Landing Page

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm working on http://pizzli.com/paystream/landing-page/. I have it perfect on desktop devices, but the text doesn't seem to want to center on mobile devices. My media queries are below:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .container p{

    }
#logomain{
    width:50%!important;
    }
input{
    margin-left:15px!important;
    height:50px!important;
}
#form{
    min-height:500px!important;
}
#contentmain{
    margin-top:10px!important;
}
.mktoButton{
position:absolute;
left:110px;
}
.subtitle{
    font-size:18px;
}
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about the para then you have fixed the width for `<p>` `width: 800px;`

Comment: this is the lesser of your problems, but for the problem described, simply change `.container p{width:100%}`. This won't solve ALL other issues you have, though, and there are a lot